# Android 9 patch image not showing up when I use Button

Tags: android, imagebutton, nine-patch

I am trying to use a 9 patch image as a button in my layout. The 9 patch image button is working only for the right most button (with id tab_btn_C). I am not sure what is wrong. The images seem to be right, and I have saved them with the right file names with a .9.png in the drawable-hdpi/drawable-mdpi folders.

The other bizarre thing is - the below layout appears to be working, if I use ImageButton instead of Button. Any help is appreciated.

Layout file

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/questions_list_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/logo"
                >

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/tab_left_btn"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/tab_btn_left"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="A"/>

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/tab_middle_btn"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/tab_btn_middle"
                    android:text="B"/>

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/tab_btn_C"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/tab_btn_right"
                    android:text="C"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Selector files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_left_active"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_left" />
</selector>
```

Comment: can you upload the 9-patch file?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was something wrong with the way the 9 patch image was being created. I created it again, and it fixed itself. I used this http://android10.org/index.php/articlesother/279-draw-9-patch-tutorial for detailed instructions in creating a 9 patch.

Thanks!